# Navigate in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I trying to navigate in react-native, this is my source

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import EmployeeList from './components/EmployeeList';
import EmployeeCreate from './components/EmployeeCreate';

const AddButton = (param) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(param)}>
    <Text style={styles.addButtonStyle}>Add</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

const styles = {
  addButtonStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginRight: 25,
    color: '#007AFF'
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginLeft: 50
  }
};

const RouterComponent = StackNavigator({
  EmployeeList: {
    screen: EmployeeList,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Employee List',
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: AddButton()
    }
  },
  EmployeeCreate: {
    screen: EmployeeCreate,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Employee Create'
    }
  },
  Home: {
    screen: LoginForm,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Please, Log In',
      headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle
    }
  }
});

export default RouterComponent;
```

Actually what I need, it's in my `const AddButton` reach `this.props.navigation.navigate('EmployeeCreate');` for me be able to navigate to `EmployeeCreate` from `AddButton`, but `AddButton` doesn't have any `props`. I'm tried to throw `props` as parameter in `AddButton`, but nothing good happen. Anybody know, how fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the EmployeeList component in the StackNavigator, you can define the navigationOptions as such:

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => 
return {
  title: 'Employee List',
  headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
  headerLeft: null,
  headerRight: AddButton(navigation)
}
```

Then in the AddButton component, you can already use the navigation.navigate function.